# Equivalent API of `tf.norm` of Tensorflow 1.+ for Tensorflow0.11

Tags: api, numpy, tensorflow, pip, euclidean-distance

I want to run [this code](https://github.com/rothk/Stabilizing_GANs#js-regularizer--regularized-gan-objective). It's written in Py3 and TF v1.4+ However it throws a an error. The [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) in `Discriminator_Regularizer` function doesn't exist in TF 0.11. I couldn't find the equivalent in TF v0.11. I can't upgrade for some CUDA/Cudnn build/install issues.

I used [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) instead but it gives a conjugate error, which is perhaps because of the type error of the Graph nodes.

How can I implement `tf.norm` in the earlier versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Euclidean norm):

```
def norm(tensor, axis=None, keep_dims=False):
  result = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tensor * tf.conj(tensor), axis, keep_dims=True))
  if not keep_dims:
    result = tf.squeeze(result, axis)
  return result
```